# Unity Tutorial, IEnumerator ShotEffect(), error

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

[Unity Version 5.6.1f1; Visual Studio 2017]

Hi,
I am going through a basic Unity FPS tutorial using Raycast. I get an error when calling

private IEnumerator ShotEffect()

as follows,

> Feature "local Functions" is not available in C#4. Please use Language version 7 or greater.

How do I fix this? This is copy/pasted from a Unity Tutorial. Is there an alternative to this type call? https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/lets-try/shooting-with-raycasts?playlist=41639&_ga=2.32575166.1847645017.1499027918-1229599585.1498623818

```
 void Update() {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            // Update the time when our player can fire next
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

            // Start our ShotEffect coroutine to turn our laser line on and off
            StartCoroutine(ShotEffect()); //**Call here**

            // Create a vector at the center of our camera's viewport
            Vector3 rayOrigin = fpsCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));

            // Declare a raycast hit to store information about what our raycast has hit
            RaycastHit hit;


        }

         private IEnumerator ShotEffect() //**Error here**
        {
            // Play the shooting sound effect
            gunAudio.Play();

            // Turn on our line renderer
            laserLine.enabled = true;

            //Wait for .07 seconds
            yield return shotDuration;

            // Deactivate our line renderer after waiting
            laserLine.enabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `ShotEffect` **inside** the `Update` function. Check your braces.

```
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            // Update the time when our player can fire next
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

            // Start our ShotEffect coroutine to turn our laser line on and off
            StartCoroutine(ShotEffect()); //**Call here**

            // Create a vector at the center of our camera's viewport
            Vector3 rayOrigin = fpsCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));

            // Declare a raycast hit to store information about what our raycast has hit
            RaycastHit hit;

        }

    } // Add brace here

    private IEnumerator ShotEffect()
    {
        // Play the shooting sound effect
        gunAudio.Play();

        // Turn on our line renderer
        laserLine.enabled = true;

        //Wait for .07 seconds
        yield return shotDuration;

        // Deactivate our line renderer after waiting
        laserLine.enabled = false;
    }
```